# How to get "Data" field from xhr.responseText?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have `XMLHttpRequest()` function given below

```
var searchFriendRequests = function (userid) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:6344/api/Registeration/searchFriendrequests?userid=' + userid, false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                var data = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

where `xhr.responseText` returns value as

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "ContentEncoding": null,
    "ContentType": null,
    "Data": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "email": "anu@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "$id": "3",
            "email": "anu@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "JsonRequestBehavior": 1,
    "MaxJsonLength": null,
    "RecursionLimit": null
}
```

How can I get the `Data` field from the `responseText`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), like:

```
var data=xhr.responseText;
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(jsonResponse["Data"]);
```

Answer (score 14):

You first need to parse responseText in JSON, for this you should use [**JSON.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Then you can access it using key.

```
var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
var yourData = json.Data; // or json["Data"]
```

Answer (score 3):

To simply get the email, or any other field, from the `Data` object, use the following:

```
data.Data[0].email
```

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SvVUc/)

Answer (score 2):

For sometime now you can use:

```
xhr.responseJSON
```

without any parsing needed. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

should parse the response  to json object first,then get the data field from the response

```
var responseText = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText),
     data = responseText.Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make your ajax request you can provide [`dataType` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#data-types):

```
dataType: 'json'
```

For such request when you receive response:

> If `json` is specified, the response is parsed using `jQuery.parseJSON` before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed JSON object is made available through the `responseJSON` property of the `jqXHR` object.

you can access your data like:

```
var data =  xhr.responseJSON
```

Full example:

```
  $ajax.({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( xhr ) {
      var yourData =  xhr.responseJSON;
      console.log( yourData );
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
console.log(jsonResponse);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your code-only answer to add information. Please do so to add explanation, that would help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.